# Setting an overall timeout for the whole WinHttp request

Tags: winhttp

WinHttp library provides [WinHttpSetTimeouts function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsettimeouts) to set timeouts for different stages of sending/receiving an HTTP request/response. The requirement is to set an overall timeout for the whole process from the time we obtain a session handle, open the request, connect to the server, send the request, and receive the response, etc.

Is there any API or approach to set a timeout for the whole overall stages of sending an HTTP request via WinHttp?

Comment: WinHTTP does not offer what you are asking for. You will have to implement your own timeout in your own code, and use callbacks to cancel operations in progress if the timeout elapses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems that WinHttp lets us to call WinHttpSetTimeouts multiple times on the same session handle before WinHttpConnect, WinHttpOpenRequest, WinHttpSendRequest, ...; Do you think if at each stage, we provide the remaining time that would work? I'll test it though.

Comment: I have no clue if that will work or not.